# md5 on google storage text files

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, md5

I do a a md5 check on the local file and the remote file to see if I should down load the file from google storage or not, I do the following on the local files:

```
def md5(self,file_name):
        hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
        with open(file_name, "rb") as f:
            for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(4096), b""):
                hash_md5.update(chunk)
        
        return base64.b64encode(hash_md5.digest()).decode("utf8")
```

this works as expected for zip-files, but for csv-files the hash don't match the remote.

example of zip files:
local: cnNcwnBzQQ8py2cR5So7Sw==
remote: cnNcwnBzQQ8py2cR5So7Sw==

example of csv-files:
local: ICArEEpdMk1RdS6qDHyNww==
remote: eKN+IclA+e9t+5r7UFPFog==

looking att content-encoding on the remote files I see that they are gzip'd, so tried to gzip the local file before hashing, but still no match.

meta data of example file:

```
Creation time:          Wed, 05 Aug 2020 02:40:40 GMT
    Update time:            Wed, 05 Aug 2020 02:40:40 GMT
    Storage class:          STANDARD
    Content-Encoding:       gzip
    Content-Length:         1479
    Content-Type:           text/csv; charset=utf-16le
    Hash (crc32c):          P6gUMw==
    Hash (md5):             X5HB70w6LAHrv/S6X45gtw==
    ETag:                   COKRu+GEg+sCEAE=
    Generation:             1596595240880354
    Metageneration:         1
```

and if I checksum after gzip I get:
ZsAm2/pMSDn5qWBzFuIFVg==

does it has anything to do with "charset=utf-16le"?

I can't get it to work for the csv-files, any ideas?

Comment: I tried with `md5sum` and I validated the [remote object md5](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/hash) with `gsutils -h -m gs://[bucketname]/[object]` and my hashes match, please try with terminal and if not work,please add the upload code that you are using.

Comment: I'm downloading and not uploading, please try again with a file that you do not have locally, check md5 on remote file (make sure it's a text file with content_encoding gzip, then download it and check md5 on local file, thx

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your issue the `zip`  files looks unaffected because the content of the object is already compressed for this reason the hashes are the same.

In the other hand, plain text could be compressed by using different levels of compression and this makes the MD5 vary, this the main reason about you are seeing different MD5 strings between your local crafted `gzip` and the Cloud stored object.

For example this is the size and the hash of my cloud object:

```
Size: 34713092
Hash: e7bc7678e973c466f15c74164ad45ad7
```

I gzipped the downloaded file with the command `gzip -9` (highest compression) and I get a completely different object

```
Size: 34694089
Hash: 88ced4e73a1b757ed264dc731649a18a
```

Comment: Based on your information I tried all compression levels but still could not get any to match the remote hash, any ideas how to move forward?

Comment: I'm not sure if cloud storage applies an extra compression or optimization on the cloud, in my research the closest was gzip with level 8